# lsqcurvefit input parameters matlab

Tags: matlab, function, curve-fitting, curve, data-fitting

I have a large set of x-data and a large set of y-data that form a series of irregular lorentzian peaks. I am trying to use the builtin matlab function lsqcurvefit

```
X = lsqcurvefit(FUN,X0,XDATA,YDATA)
```

I know what `X0`, `XDATA`, `YDATA` are, but I am struggling with what to put in for `FUN`. I created the following function but gut an error message from matlab saying that:

```
function is undefined for arguments of type 'double'
```

my function:

```
function F = myfun(c,xdata)
F = c(1) + c(2)*exp(-1*(xdata-c(3)).^2/c(4).^2);
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should/could be using for `FUN` instead of the function I have already been using? 
Thanks!!

Comment: When calling lsqcurvefit, I have been using X=lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make an anonymous function and make sure your initial guess vector is of the correct dimension.  Set X0 to be your initial guess for the curve fit parameters, and make sure X0 is a 1x4 vector, you may want to add your initial value to your question to make it clear what problem you are trying to solve.

```
% setup your initial guess, this is just an example
X0 = [ 1 1 1 1];
X = lsqcurvefit(@(c,xdata) c(1)+(c(2)*exp(-1*(((xdata-c(3)).^2)/(c(4)).^2))),X0,XDATA,YDATA);
```

When I test the above I get:

```
% assign the anon function to a handle
me = @(c,xdata) c(1)+(c(2)*exp(-1*(((xdata-c(3)).^2)/(c(4)).^2)))
% test the function
me([1,1,1,1],1)
ans =

     2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But when I put in c=[1 1 1] I got this error:
Attempted to access c(4); index out of bounds because numel(c)=3.

Error in @(c,x)c(1)+(c(2)*exp(-1*(((xdata-c(3)).^2)/(c(4)).^2)))


Error in lsqcurvefit (line 203)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot
    continue.
 


What exactly do you mean by c=[ some stuff here ]; ??

Comment: Likely because you're using a 1x4 vector, not a 1x3, did you mean to include a `c(4)` element?  Sorry about my original post, read your question too fast, ;-)

Comment: No worries! I changed c to c=[1 1 1 1] but still got this as an error:

Attempted to access c(4); index out of bounds because numel(c)=3.

Error in @(c,xdata)c(1)+(c(2)*exp(-1*(((xdata-c(3)).^2)/(c(4)).^2)))


Error in lsqcurvefit (line 203)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot
    continue.


Any other ideas why this isn't working?